# BERT fine-tuning with Estimators on TPUs on colab TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-estimator, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

i wrote a jupyter-notebook on google's colab to fine-tune (for text classification) a version BERT that i already pretrained on Arabic only. And i couldn't get around this error when the training starts.

I followed the notebook given by google on [github](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/bert_finetuning_with_cloud_tpus.ipynb#scrollTo=uu2dQ_TId-uH)

Model Building Code:

```py
model_fn = model_fn_builder(
  bert_config=modeling.BertConfig.from_json_file(CONFIG_FILE),
  num_labels=len(label_list),
  init_checkpoint=INIT_CHECKPOINT,
  learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
  num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
  num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
  use_tpu=True,
  use_one_hot_embeddings=True
)


tpu_cluster_resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_ADDRESS)

run_config = tf.contrib.tpu.RunConfig(
    cluster=tpu_cluster_resolver,
    model_dir=OUTPUT_DIR,
    save_checkpoints_steps=SAVE_CHECKPOINTS_STEPS,
    tpu_config=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUConfig(
        iterations_per_loop=ITERATIONS_PER_LOOP,
        num_shards=NUM_TPU_CORES,
        per_host_input_for_training=tf.contrib.tpu.InputPipelineConfig.PER_HOST_V2))

estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
    use_tpu=USE_TPU,
    model_fn=model_fn,
    config=run_config,
    train_batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
    eval_batch_size=EVAL_BATCH_SIZE,
    predict_batch_size=PREDICT_BATCH_SIZE,)

train_input_fn = input_fn_builder(
    features=train_features,
    seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
    is_training=True,
    drop_remainder=False)

#tf.reset_default_graph()
print(f'Beginning Training!')
current_time = datetime.now()
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=TRAIN_STEPS)
print("Training took time ", datetime.now() - current_time)
```

error code:

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tpu/tpu_sharding.py in _unshard_shape(self, shape)
    214                        (shape.as_list(), self._shard_dimension))
    215     dims = shape.as_list()
--> 216     dims[self._shard_dimension] *= self._number_of_shards
    217     return tensor_shape.as_shape(dims)
    218 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Parameters and the rest of the code are in this shared copy of the colab notebook: [colab_link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gcGphzAIS5OCIADz6SPycA580gR6w1pv#scrollTo=xe57J1zpc6iT)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this. I am facing similar issue

Comment: Yes, drop remainder should be equal to true when using TPUs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning the Answer in this Section (even though it is answered in Comments Section), for the benefit of the Community.

Setting the parameter, `drop_remainder` to `True` in the function, `input_fn_builder` has resolved the issue.

Respective Code Snippet is shown below:

```
train_input_fn = input_fn_builder(
    features=train_features,
    seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
    is_training=True,
    drop_remainder=False)
```